# google chart put data in AreaChart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I put sum data in my chart google Areachart
Code google chart

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(talk);
  function talk() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?=$talks ?>]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Nb De J\'aime',
          hAxis: {title: 'Jours',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0},
          pointSize: 10
        };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('parle'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

and

```
$talks=['01',422],['02',440],['03',477],['04',523],['05',565],['06',609],['07',651],['08',708],['09',747],['10',759],['11',793],['12',860],['13',975],['14',1118],['15',1317],['16',1441],['17',1529],['18',1686],['19',1765],['20',1879],['21',2122],['22',2245],['23',2329],['24',2719],['25',3600],['26',4068],['27',4747],['28',5479],['18',1686],['19',1765],['20',1879],['21',2122],['22',2245],['23',2329],['24',2719],['25',3600],['26',4068],['27',4747],['28',5479],['29',6082],
```

and i have this pic for my graph
[image]

Comment: What is the exact query here ?

Comment: the result is put in variabl $talks

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ti Amo Laky: you didn't ask a question so it's hard to answer :-). But my assumption is that 1st point is missing and step in the middle of chart is bothering you.

You did not define a header for your data. The first array has to be something like:

```
        ['Jours', 'Number'], ['01', 422],...
```

You have duplicated data after point 28: points 18 to 28 are repeated with exactly same values. If you remove those repeated values you will get the following picture:

[image]